# Meta tag for tag-request

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

I think it would be helpful to have a meta tag `tag-request` in order to distinguish requests for new tags from other tag-related questions. Are there any reasons why this is hasn't been implemented?

Comment: You wot, m8? I... my mind *bends* just trying to understand how many levels of meta this question has.

Comment: We need a meta for the meta, bruh `Feature Request!`

Comment: Can someone help me understand why this is being downvoted? I'm relatively new here - am I missing something?

Comment: On the Meta site, upvotes and downvotes indicate agreement or disagreement.  So far, 1 person agrees and 6 disagree.  The disagreement is likely because this would be covered by [tags], there is already perhaps too much granulation. and many [tag-cleanup-request] questions involve proposing new tags, so it would add to tag bloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really *need* to be implemented.

The only users this affects are those with less than [300 reputation](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-tags), and if they feel that their question needs a tag then they should first ask their question and apply whatever tags that are relevant and currently exist.  They would then come to meta and request that their question is **re-tagged** with an extra tag that would have to be created.

Users with more than 300 reputation would just create the tag, thus not needing to request it in the first place.

A new tag should never be created without a question to attach it to. If a tag is created but not applied to any questions then it will be noticed by one of the nightly scripts and deleted, thus orphaning any wiki excerpts that might have been filled out.

As a result we've never needed *tag* requests without first having to *retag* a question first, hence we only need [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request).

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me. The reason I was asking is because I wanted to post a question which I think needs a new tag (as well as some related tags I think need to be implemented), so I'll post my question and put in a `retag-request`